# How to de- and increase the font size with WKWebView?

Tags: fonts, font-size, wkwebview

In Safari you can increase and decrease the font size. How can I achieve the same effect with WKWebView?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The codes suggested by Inna used to work but stopped working from iOS10.3. I did some research and found that we need to make a slight change to it, just changing "%%" to a single "%".

So JS code should be:

```
let js = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust='\(fontSize)%'"
```

I got this info from Apple Developer forum.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51079

Comment: iOS 16: works well on iPhone, but not on iPad!

Answer (score 7):

Swift **5** solution:

Implement `WKNavigationDelegate` and in `viewDidLoad` :

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

then in `didFinish` :

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    let js = "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust='200%'"//dual size
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: this didn't work now Xcode 12.4 Swift 5.2

Comment: @ĐứcBùi try to chanje injected Js. It may be fixed by changing js

Comment: Works for me in Xcode 13.4.1 thanks!

Comment: @StuP. glad to know

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have fontUpdatedHeight integer which gives you the exact fontsize.

Just create string like that:

```
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%lu%%'",(unsigned long)fontUpdatedHeight];
```

And execute the NSString

```
[self.WKWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

Comment: This used to work great, but it stopped working from latest Xcode (Xcode8.3.2). Is there anyone who is facing the same problem? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I don't think it's stopped. You should review your codes again?

Comment: Oh, really? Which version of Xcode are you using and what is iOS version of your device? I am using XCode 8.3.2 & iOS10.3.1. There seems to be people like me at Apple Developer Forum too (please scroll to the bottom)https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51079

Comment: WKWebView doesn't have a `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString` method; that's UIWebView.

Comment: It works perfect with UIWebView but not with WKWebView
but UIWebView is depreciated

Comment: I think now is [self.webview evaluateJavaScript: completion];