# WKWebView: unable to change font size

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

## The **problem**:

I am trying to resize the text / content that is being displayed in a `WKWebView`. The content itself is loaded from a remote source (via `loadHTMLString`), so I cannot change the css.

I already tried most other solutions I could find on stack overflow (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/43694902/1673377), but none seem to work.

## Some **background**:

Xcode 9.2, Swift 4, iOS 10 / 11.

To monitor the content size, I used the code taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511422/1673377

```
lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    //Javascript string
    let source = "window.onload=function () {window.webkit.messageHandlers.sizeNotification.postMessage({justLoaded:true,height: document.body.scrollHeight});};"
    let source2 = "document.body.addEventListener( 'resize', incrementCounter); function incrementCounter() {window.webkit.messageHandlers.sizeNotification.postMessage({height: document.body.scrollHeight});};"
    
    //UserScript object
    let script = WKUserScript(source: source, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    
    let script2 = WKUserScript(source: source2, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    
    //Content Controller object
    let controller = WKUserContentController()
    
    //Add script to controller
    controller.addUserScript(script)
    controller.addUserScript(script2)
    
    //Add message handler reference
    controller.add(self, name: "sizeNotification")
    
    //Create configuration
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.userContentController = controller
    
    return WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)
}()
```

To disable zooming, I also evaluate the following JavaScript:

```
"var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);"
```

(I tried playing around with the values for `initial-scale` and `maximum-scale`, but to no avail.)

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Basic Goal**

If you want to change the font size, you somehow need CSS. Your goal therefore should be to inject the following 2 lines somewhere in the html header:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'/> // This may help with scale
```

If you add a `style.css` file to your project, it now should be respected.

**Actual implementation**

I don't know how the html you receive from the server is configured, but you could try to manipulate it a bit like this before loading it onto the `WKWebView`:

```
let customHeader = <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'><meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'/>
let newHtml = serverHtml.replacingOccurrences(of: "<head>", with: "<head>" + customHeader)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I went with something similar to your idea - in the HTML's header (in `<head><style>*</style></head>`), I appended / injected `body,html { font-size: \(zoomLevel); }`, with `zoomLevel` being a percentage value (i.e. 50, 100, 150, ...).